# SQL Performance degrades on adding INNER JOIN clause in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have the following query

```
SELECT pri.*
  FROM patientreceiptitem pri 
  JOIN patientfinancialtransaction_patientreceiptitem pp ON pri.id = pp.receiptitems_id
  JOIN patientfinancialtransaction pft ON pp.patientfinancialtransaction_id = pft.id 
 WHERE pri.createtime >= '2020-03-01'
   AND pri.createtime < '2020-04-01'
```

It runs in 1.79 seconds and gives an output of 111, 793 rows

However, when I add a condition that is more restrictive as follows:

```
 JOIN patientbillconcession pbc ON pbc.id = pft.concession_id
```

the performance degrades dramatically. It now takes 8.185 seconds for an output of 10,338 rows. The same degradation is seen if I add a condition to the JOIN clause for the `pft` table:

```
SELECT pri.*
  FROM patientreceiptitem pri 
  JOIN patientfinancialtransaction_patientreceiptitem pp ON pri.id = pp.receiptitems_id
  JOIN patientfinancialtransaction pft ON pp.patientfinancialtransaction_id = pft.id 
       AND pft.concession_id IS NOT NULL
 WHERE pri.createtime >= '2020-03-01'
   AND pri.createtime < '2020-04-01'
```

`concession_id` is indexed in the `pft` table.

Any pointers would be great.

Explain Plan for this case: https://explain.depesz.com/s/jpof

I'm running Postgres 12 on Arch Linux. My client is DBeaver 7.3.2.

Update 1:
I found that changing the following to a LEFT JOIN completes the query in 1.914 seconds:
`LEFT JOIN patientbillconcession pbc ON pbc.id = pft.concession_id`

Explain Plan for this case: https://explain.depesz.com/s/KtaZ

But adding `AND pft.concession_id IS NOT NULL` to the WHERE clause once again degrades the performance to 7.938 seconds

Comment: Please provide query plane for both cases

Comment: Without `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output, all is guesswork.

Comment: https://explain.dalibo.com might be helpful

Comment: The execution plan is better show as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). To do that, copy the execution plan as returned by running `explain (analyze, buffers format text)` as "plain text", then paste this text into your question and put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Or upload it to https://explain.depesz.com/

Comment: The people who can most likely help you are accustomed to reading raw EXPLAIN results, not whatever weird (and apparently buggy) think dbeaver is doing to those ones.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks for the pointer. I was unsure in what format to share the plan.

Comment: @jjanes, I fully agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be able to tell you a bit about what the planner is thinking here, although I don't know exactly why it goes wrong.  In the top 2 nodes of the slow plan, you can see the second one is far higher than the first one (2,234,398.29  vs  20,326.53).  So it is thinking the highest value of pbc.id it finds in the last node (patientbillconcession) will be very small, and that it can abandon the 2nd node's execution once the returned value of pft.concession_id exceeds the highest observed value of pbc.id, and that this will happen after doing <1% of the work of the gather merge and the nodes below it.  (On the other hand, the expected row counts from the top two nodes are the same, so that seems inconsistent with this "thinks it can stop early" theory, so maybe there is a planner bug here.  Can you reproduce this with randomly generated data?).

What can you do about it?  First step would be VACUUM ANALYZE everything to make sure you still have the problem with fresh stats.

If that doesn't work, you can use the big guns and just wrap the fast query in `with t as materialized (...)` and then join "t" to patientbillconcession.  But if you have many similar queries with similar problems, it would be a bit tedious to fix them one by one in this way.

If you can share some anonymized version of the data which still has the problem, or better yet a generator script to generate random data which has the problem, we could get closer to a root cause.

Looking at the slowest step of the slowest plan, I wonder if an index on pri (id, createtime) would help avoid hitting the table so often for rows that turn out not to qualify?  I suspect that this where the time is actually going, doing those 198,280 random reads.  (turning track_io_timing on and repeating could help clarify that part).

Comment: thanks! VACUUM ANALYZE has solved the problem. Thanks much for the detailed thoughts too!